# Is this an equivalence relation? $xRy$ if and only if $|x+y| = |x| + |y|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I can prove that it is reflexive, but I am not sure how to formally prove that this relation is symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Note that $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same sign (with the convention of $0$ being positive and negative)

Comment: This is the set of all vectors that have the same direction.  "The shortest distance between two points is a straight line" sort of thing.  Depends on whether you include the origin.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$|1+0|=|1|+|0|$$

$$|0-1|=|0|+|-1|$$

To check symmetric:

Notice that $|x+y|=|y+x|$ and $|x|+|y|=|y|+|x|$, hence if $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$, what can you conclude about $|y+x|$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick, as in the above hint, $x=-1$
$y=0$
$z=2$

We have that $xRy$, because $|x+y|=|-1 + 0| = |-1| + |0|=|x|+|y|$,

$yRz$, because $|y+z| = |0+2| = |0| + |2|$

But from the fact that the following is false
$1=|-1+2| = |-1| + |2|=3$
it does not follow that $xRz$.